# VS2010 : MSVSMON.exe failed to start

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2008, windows

i convert a vs 2008 windows application to vs 2010 but when i am debug that project it builds successfully but it is not debugging.

this is the error message.

[image]

Comment: You don't ever "have" to convert. Just start a 2010 project of the same type bring the files required to compile into the project and build a new solution. That way you don't have to choose to back the 2008 up or worry about needing it in 2008 later. This way the 2008 solution stays in tact, while still having the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Project, "Use Custom web server" checkbox will be selected, select check box "Use local IIS web server". I resolved this issue with this and its working.